# Atualizar PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5

Como faço para atualizar uma partialview (asp .net) após eu selecionar alguma informação pai, por exemplo:

Tenho uma lista de notas fiscais e uma partialview ao lado para mostrar os itens dessa nota.
Ao selecionar uma das notas fiscais a minha partialview deve buscar os itens de acordo a nota selecionada, como fazer?

Comment: Utilizando `ajax`. Você deverá implementar alguma função em javascript que monitore as alterações e que faça a busca no servidor das informações necessárias.

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo Richard Dias?

Comment: Acredito que isso poderá te dar uma ideia do que fazer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemente uma função que utilize `ajax` para realizar a comunicação com uma controller (`DetalheNotaFiscalController`, por exemplo):

```
function DetalharNotaFiscal(idNota) {
    $.post("/DetalheNotaFiscal/Detalhar", { id: idNota }).done(function (retorno) {
        $("#detalhe_nf").html(retorno); //id da div com a partial, recebendo o retorno da controller
    }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
        alert("Erro Interno. Favor contatar o administrador.");
    });
}
```

Na controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Detalhar(string id)
{
    //TODO: Recuperação da nota através do id
    var model = TODO; //model da partial view

    return PartialView("Index", model);
}
```